# passing a double pointer by reference

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, dynamic-memory-allocation, double-pointer

I'm getting an error saying my expression must have a pointer to type class, I'm trying to dynamically allocate an array of pointers to an object vector.

```
void dmaArr(Record*** sortedRec, vector<Record> records) {
    //sortedRec = nullptr;
    *sortedRec = new Record *[records.size()];
    cout << *sortedRec << endl << sortedRec << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
        *sortedRec[i] = &records[i];
        cout << sortedRec[i]->name << '\t' << &sortedRec[i]->name << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `cout` statement, `sortedRec[i]` has type `Record**`, which you cannot use with the pointer dereference operator.  You can use `(*sortedRec[i])->name` to get the name field of the record just assigned.

Incidentally, because you pass `records` by value, all the pointers stored in your for loop are to this temporary object and will be danging once the function returns.  You should pass `records` by reference: `vector<Record> &records` to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

`sortedRec` is a `Record***`, so `sortedRec[i]` is a `Record**`.  You can't use the `->` operator to dereference a pointer-to-pointer.  You need to use the `*` operator instead to dereference the `Record**` pointer-to-pointer into a single `Record*` pointer, like you do in your `for` loop.  Then, you can use the `->` operator to dereference that `Record*` pointer to access the members of the `Record` instance, eg:

```cpp
cout << (*sortedRec[i])->name << endl;
```

That being said, VERY VERY RARELY in C++ do you ever need to use 3 levels of indirection, like you are (`Record*** sortedRec`).

No matter how `sortedRec` is passed, `records` should be passed by reference so that `dmaArr()` is not acting on a *copy* of the caller's `vector<Record>`, leaving `sortedRec` holding dangling pointers when the *copy* is destroyed when `dmaArr()` exits:

```cpp
void dmaArr(..., vector<Record> &records)
```

Then, you can *and should* replace one level of pointer indirection on `sortedRec` by using a reference instead of a pointer:

```cpp
void dmaArr(Record** &sortedRec, vector<Record> records) {
    sortedRec = new Record *[records.size()];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < records.size(); ++i) {
        sortedRec[i] = &records[i];
        cout << sortedRec[i]->name << endl;
    }
    ...
}
```

```cpp
vector<Record> records;
Record** sortedRecords;

// populate records as needed...

dmaArr(sortedRecords, records);

// use sortedRecords as needed...

delete [] sortedRecords;
```

Then, you can *and should* replace another level of pointer indirection on `sortedRec` by using `std::vector` instead of `new[]`.  Let `std::vector` manage the dynamic memory for you, especially since the caller is already using `std::vector` anyway:

```cpp
void dmaArr(vector<Record*> &sortedRec, vector<Record> &records) {
    sortedRec.resize(records.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < records.size(); ++i) {
        sortedRec[i] = &records[i];
        cout << sortedRec[i]->name << endl;
    }
    ...
}
```

```cpp
vector<Record> records;
vector<Record*> sortedRecords;

// populate records as needed...

dmaArr(sortedRecords, records);

// use sortedRecords as needed...
```

Comment: The ``` (** &sortedRec) ``` doesn't change the value in main. I agree on using another vector, but I was pushed to write it with dma array of pointers pointing to my vector for.

Comment: `Record** &sortedRec` DOES change the pointer in `main()`, if you call it like `Record** sortedRec; dmaArr(sortedRec, ...);` instead of like `Record** sortedRec; dmaArr(&sortedRec, ...);` I have updated my answer to demonstrate this. This is C++, not C, you should not use pointers where references will suffice.